# use fundamental theorem of calculus to find a function $f(x)$ and a number $a$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I thought I understood the fundamental theorem of calculus but I'm confused on the following problem..

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find a function $f(x)$ and
a number $a$ so that $a+\int_{4}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt=2\sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$.

I don't have the answer to check but what I did was take the derivative of both sides of the equation which means $a$ could be any number because it's derivative will be zero and the derivative of the integral is $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ and the derivative of the right hand side is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ so I determined $f(x)$ would have to equal $x^{3/2}$

Am I correct? or could someone please explain the method to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: you are on the right track.

Comment: **Hint**: To find $a$, what happens at $x=4$?

Comment: @Daryl when x is 4 the R.H.S. is 4 and the integral is 0 so a would have to be 4? What if x is not 4 then wouldn't a be something else?

Comment: @Devin Since $a$ is constant, $a=4$ for all $x$ as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Differentiate both sides of the given equation (using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate the term with the integral:

\begin{align}
a+\int_{4}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt&=2\sqrt{x}\tag{1}\\
{f(x)\over x^2}&=x^{-1/2}\\
f(x)&=x^{3/2}.
\end{align}

To determine the value of the constant $a$, revisit the original equation $(1)$, now knowing that $f(t)=t^{3/2}$:
\begin{align}
a+\int_{4}^{x}\frac{t^{3/2}}{t^2}\,dt&=2\sqrt{x}\\
a+\int_{4}^{x}t^{-1/2}\,dt&=2\sqrt{x}\\
a+2t^{1/2}\Big|_{4}^{x}&=2\sqrt{x}\\
a+2\left(x^{1/2}-4^{1/2}\right)&=2\sqrt{x}\\
a&=4
\end{align}

An alternative to this last method is simply to evaluate $(1)$ at $x=4$ since this makes the integral term vanish:
$$
a+\int_4^4 {f(t)\over t^2}\,dt=2\sqrt{4}\implies a+0=2\cdot 2\implies a=4.
$$